# Is there a terran world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would very much like to play in a world with everything in it: every biome, dungeon, etc. I would like one where there are poles; i.e., ice to the far north and south. I would prefer spawn to be in a jungle, but anything with trees and fruit would be okay, as long as the distribution of biomes is realistic to how a planet would form them. My edition is PE 0.16.05.

Comment: Hi Demo! Your question really has a lot to chew though, but I don't feel that anyone can give you a good answer with all the different questions in it.  You might want to edit your question and prune down to one or two questions that people can answer at once.

Comment: It has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minecraft's world generation isn't realistic. There is no option that lets you choose exactly what you want in your world. (Except the custom worlds in PC edition, but that won't let you achieve what you're looking for either)

However, you can still try to find a world that fits what you're looking for. You can do this by finding the right seed.

A minecraft world seed represents the terrain of the world. If you generate a world, and like the terrain, you can make a new world with the same seed, and all of the landforms of the new world will match the landforms of the old world exactly.

Try creating searching through seeds by generating worlds in creative until you find a seed that meets your needs. Once you find a seed that looks realistic enough, recreate that world in survival using the same seed.

Unfortunately, finding seeds is a difficult  task. You may have to make hundreds of worlds before you find one that's realistic. I think you'll just have to accept the way minecraft generates its worlds.

Don't worry too much though. Even if you have to pick a world that is less than perfect, you can be sure that it has every biome because worlds in minecraft are infinite (IIRC this is now true in PE as well).

Comment: Just a small note:  The seed itself doesn't contain information about the world. Rather, Minecraft uses maths formulas to create the chunks of the world and a Random Number Generator (RNG) to fill in the first time numbers. - Computers have a very hard time being random though, and can generate the same RNG results if it's conditions are always the same. [As such, MC was programed to allow players to add a SEED to the RNG machine](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Seed_(level_generation)), there-by making it possible for the same world to be recreated by getting the same results each time.